# OrientDB: How to get list of top edges from a single vertex

Tags: orientdb

How to get a list of top edges from one edge using Java API?

I have a vertex with number of edges. I want to retrieve top 10 edges of a specific class ranked by a property in this edge. How to do this?

The edge class is `HasEdge` and the property I have is `repetitions`.

So, initial idea is to do a query against the vertex but how to get the top list of edges? 
`vertes.query().??`

Answer (score 1):

If `MyVertex` is the Vertex with number of `HasEdge` Edges and `myProperty` is the property used for the ranking, then this is the query needed:

```
select * from HasEdge order by myProperty desc limit 10 where out = #9:0
```

(`MyVertex` has RID #9:0 is assumed here, can be replaced by `select ...`)